# Pagination links Updating Query fails

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, pagination

I am using Ajax based CodeIgniter pagination. I am fetching records after applying filters like this by CodeIgniter query.

```
$data["results"] = $this->jobs_model->get_fourteen_jobs($search, $city_filter, $type, $min_salary, $max_salary, $industry, $config["per_page"], $records_from);
```

now I am doing pagination by using this code:

```
    $config["per_page"] = 14;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;

        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
        $config['first_link'] = false;
        $config['last_link'] = false;
        $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['prev_link'] = '&laquo';
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
        $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['next_link'] = '&raquo';
        $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

        $config['num_links'] = 3;

$config["total_rows"] = $this->jobs_model->total_jobs();

        $config['attributes'] = array('onClick' => 'myFunction(event, this)');


    $this->pagination->initialize($config);



 $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    echo json_encode($data);exit;
```

Records are getting updated after applying filters but pages are not getting updated. When we click on extra pages it shows no records. I want extra pages to be eliminated.

Answer (score 0):

i got what was wrong. i am giving count of all the jobs to pagination and every time it was putting all the pages in pagination in this line of code.

```
$config["total_rows"] = $this->jobs_model->total_jobs();
```

i just added all the filters in there and it gives filtered records in count as well.

```
$config["total_rows"] = $this->jobs_model->total_jobs($search, $city_filter,
            $type, $min_salary, $max_salary, $industry, $config["per_page"], $records_from);
```